# rabbitmq garbage collector settings

Tags: garbage-collection, rabbitmq

We have low-latency application (messages need to be processed in less than 200ms). RabbitMQ works fine, but there are periods of time when messages are not delivered for 2-5 few seconds.
What we need to understand:

1. How to log time and duration when erlang garbage collector is running  (similarly to -XX:+PrintGC in Java). Can it really pause processing for 2-5 seconds?
2. What are the best practices regarding to setting rabbitmq GC options 'background_gc_enabled' and 'background_gc_target_interval' for low-latency applications? I would assume that running GC on background and more often will reduce pauses (our goal is to avoid long pauses). But based on documentation "disabling background GC may reduce latency for client operations" (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example), which is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: So you are ruling out the network factor...

Comment: @Soumen We have multiple queues and this problem seems to be queue related (messages in other queues between the same hosts are delivered correctly in these time periods). Therefore I would like to monitor two issues - #1 pauses because of garbage collection and #2 queue flow control.